# How best to extend a partial class for INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a simple class defined by a third party. The class is located in a separate assembly from my user interface and is defined as:

```
 public partial class View_Consultant
{
    private int _id;
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
        set
        {
            this._id = value;
        }
    }

    private int _office_recid;
    public virtual int Office_recid
    {
        get
        {
            return this._office_recid;
        }
        set
        {
            this._office_recid = value;
        }
    }
    .........................................
```

In MVVM fashion, I have need to bind the properties of this class to the user interface, so need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Do I need to create another class in the user interface assembly to inherit from View_Consultant, or is there a better way?  What is the best way to do this?

Note: The View_Consultant is built by a third party tool. So any manual change to the file itself will not be kept between builds.

Comment: Suggest to use a different template to generate code that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. There is no way to do it how you would want it without defining the properties yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the properties are already defined (and its in a different assembly), the `partial` keyword doesn't buy you anything here.

However, because the properties are `virtual` you can derive from this class and override them, including INPC in your new properties.

Comment: Anyway to simply add on the "INotifyPropertyChanged" to the virtual properties without essentially rewriting the class? Thanks. (If I have to rewrite the class, I don't see where inheritance helps at all?)

Comment: @AlanWayne The inheritance here is mostly so you can pass the derived class to third party function expecting the base class and upcast. To answer your question, no, there is no way to do that. Even using composition, you couldn't inject the PropertyChanged behavior into the property setters.